# Maximum number of proposed sites

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

I was just wondering, just like there is a max number of proposals you can commit to, is there is also a max number of sites you can propose on Area 51?

Comment: Umm, I guess there's no limit...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only commit to three proposals at a time.

As for proposals, there is no practical limit: What this means is that you can propose an unlimited number of sites, but you can only propose [one per day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=arts) (written for every category):

[image]

This is to make sure that Area 51 doesn't get "spammed" with random site ideas, and to make sure that you really want the site yourself, and to give you time and space to think about it.

Comment: Yeah, this is more of a spam-throttling mechanism rather than saying you can or should propose one crazy, unsupported idea per day.